# AWS API Gateway endpoint works fine in postman, returns 400 Bad Request in Android App

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I am getting familiar with AWS Lambda + API Gateway and am reaching a strange error. The endpoint works fine in Postman, but when I try and implement it in my app, I get a status error for 400.  Here is my code:

```
    final String body = "Name";
    final byte[] content = body.getBytes(StringUtils.UTF8);

    final ApiRequest apiRequest = new ApiRequest(client.getClass().getSimpleName())
            .withPath("/path")
            .withHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.valueOf("POST"))
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(content.length))
            .withBody(content);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                Log.e("TRY", "Thread trying");

                // Invoke the API
                final ApiResponse response = client.execute(apiRequest);

                final int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
                final String statusText = response.getStatusText();

                Log.e("API_RESPONSE", "Response Status: " + statusCode + " " + statusText);

                // TODO: Add your custom handling for server response status codes (e.g., 403 Forbidden)

            } catch (final AmazonClientException exception) {
             //   Log.e(LOG_TAG, exception.getMessage(), exception);

                // TODO: Put your exception handling code here (e.g., network error)
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Can you include your raw request in Postman and the error message you get in your android application?

Comment: Missing or incorrect content in the payload or parameters. Capture and compare the good message vs. bad message.

Comment: In Postman, I enter the `{myurl}/path`, use a POST method, and in the body just put "Name", and the response is "The name is Name", which is what should return.

Comment: I actually found the problem, I had to change the end piece of the endpoint within my code.  However, now I am getting a response status of 403 forbidden. Any thoughts as to what this could be?  My APIs are public.

Comment: Nevermind, now it is back to 400 bad request

Comment: is there more details being returned in the response body?

Comment: No.  Right now I am just using a simple function to test the api, then I am going to attempt to replace it with a more complex one once I can get it connected.